# Windows 10 Enterprise/Education/LTSC and Insecure Guest Logon issue with Printing, error 0x0000011b

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, network-printer, smb, shared-folders

The reason for this intro: there's a ton of outright false information on the Internet about this pernicious issue.

Here's the situation.

A company of a friend of mine has Windows 10 LTSC workstations without a domain, where each user has its own PC and unique login.

The Enterprise/Education/LTSC editions of Windows 10 kind of, sort of allow Public Folder Sharing without Password Protected Sharing except when they [do not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/guest-access-in-smb2-is-disabled-by-default).

Here you can see the two errors when you try to open the computer on the net via its name:

Error 0x80070035:
[image: Error 0x80070035]

And error 0x80004005 when you try to open the PC via its IP address directly:
[image: Error 0x80004005]

Microsoft posts the official "workaround" which is enabling the "AllowInsecureGuestAuth" group policy:
[image: Enable Insecure Guest Logon / AllowInsecureGuestAuth]

and it seemingly works:
[image: Can now browse network shares for the PC]

Which all brings us to the main issue. You cannot use printing for this PC because when you try to open the printer, you get error 0x0000011b:

[image: Shared printer error 0x0000011b when the Enable Insecure Guest Logon policy is enabled]

Is Windows documentation incomplete and the posted workaround doesn't fully work for printer sharing? What's the easiest workaround to get the shared printer working?

All the PCs in questions are freshly installed with zero modifications and no third-party antivirus/networking software. This all could be reproduced instantly using any VM software. I live in a country where Microsoft is not officially represented, so there's no way I can request support from them (besides in most cases it's 99.999% useless).

Comment: The guest user is absolutely there. The guest file sharing is absolutely there. Should I post screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

The posted official workaround is indeed *incomplete* and printing doesn't fully respect this group policy configuration because as a fix for [CVE-2021-1678](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-1678) Microsoft increased the printer spooler protection but they forgot to let printing work for people who don't bother too much with proper encryption and authentication which `AllowInsecureGuestAuth` *disables*.

There's a simple fix though which is to add or modify a Printer Spooler registry setting called `RpcAuthnLevelPrivacyEnabled` on **all** the affected PCs (the one which shares printers and the ones which try to print):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print]
"RpcAuthnLevelPrivacyEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

[image: RpcAuthnLevelPrivacyEnabled=0]

Restarting the Printer Spooler service is enough to apply the fix - again, must be done on all the affected PCs.

Comment: To be fair Microsoft clearly documented that the default behavior would be enforced after [September 2021](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/managing-deployment-of-printer-rpc-binding-changes-for-cve-2021-1678-kb4599464-12a69652-30b9-3d61-d9f7-7201623a8b25)

Comment: There's no connection between this article and the one about Insecure Guest Logon: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/guest-access-in-smb2-is-disabled-by-default - find anything about printing there, you won't. Microsoft is so large, looks like different groups od developers working on different parts of Windows are not well connected or organized.